# Flopy MF6 Transport Budget Inconsistancies

Tags: python, flopy

I am working with Flopy (3.3.5) and MF6 (6.2.2)  transport to simulate a plume movement towards a creek from an industrial site. I am using a structured regular grid with 6 layers flow and transport are run simultaneously, and the creek is represented in the flow model using a RIV package with Drains along the bank.
With the new ATS package the simulation works Great! and produces reasonable concentration results. The difficulty I run into is trying to extract the mass flux into the boundary conditions representing the creek, from the various budget and flux output options.
I have set up an observation package to record the mass flux across every “JA-FACE” that the boundary condition cells share with the rest of the model, and this seems to be working, but I have been trying to compare this to budget outputs and it has highlighted some inconsistencies and problems with the current output.

- •    I noticed that the model simulates very small numbers for mass flux
  rather than zero away from the plume after a few iterations. When the
  numbers with three digit exponents are written to the list file and
  csv output from the obs package the ‘E’ in the number gets
  dropped(eg.” -2.90933775-241”, while 2 digit exponent numbers are
  written fine as “-2.90933775E-41”), I have tried
  changing the number of digits on output but the behaviour seems to
  happen consistently. I have scripted a fix for the output files of
  the observation package, but I imagine this is likely why I get an
  object with all “none” entries when I try to read the list file with
  the flopy listBudget utility.
- •    I have Set the SinkSourceMixing (SSM) package to both print and
  save budget information. When I look at the output written to the
  list file (in a text editor rather than in python) the cellid’s
  (l,r,c tuple) written to the list file with the SSM information do
  not corelate to the original cellids in the stress period data of the
  original flow model packages (inconsistencies across well, River, and
  Drain packages)
- •    I have loaded the binary budget file and can select the SSM data
  using “cbb.get_data(totem=t,text=”SOURCE-SINK MIX”) to get an
  appropriate recarray. I have been calculating the node number based
  on the formula in the “get_node” method of the
  “discretization/structuredgrid” package “node=L*nrow*ncol+R*ncol+C”
  which is different to the one used in the flopy/mf6 complex model
  example notebook. Using this node number I can select the rows of the recarray
  that has it in the “node” column. When I do this I noticed that all
  of the associated entries in the “node2” column don’t seem to be
  adjacent cells from any method of trying to back out the LRC from
  node number that I can find.   When I look at the “FLOW-JA-FACE” data
  in the budget I get a consistent value for the flow across a face
  from the budget file using my calculated node number that I get from
  the observation package (defined with a L,R,C tuple) so that seems
  alright, but the summation of all flux into the cell from the
  “FLOW-JA-FACE” data does not seem to quite add up to the values in
  the SSM data in the budget.

I think for my purposes the flux into the boundary nodes I am getting out of the obs package is sufficient I just wanted to post a question documenting these observations in the hope that I can:

1. understand if its due to something in my model setup, and
2. make a bit of a contribution to the flopy/mf6 project from my experiences if they are due to issues in the codes that need to be addressed.

Thanks to all the contributors to this software package
Kevin